# Quickly updating a mass of objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

```
int X = 1;
int Y = 0;
while (X != 99 - 1 || Y != 99 - 1)
{
    Y++;
    if (Y > 99 - 1)
    {
        X += 1;
        Y = 1;
    }
    Layer1ID[X, Y].Update(X, Y);
    Layer2ID[X, Y].Update(X, Y);
}
```

This must update a total of 19602 objects each tick. Is there any way to speed this up? Threading maybe?

Objects(Ground and buildings) are stored in Layer1 and Layer2 ID Arrays of size 99x99. Most of them do nothing during the update method.

I've only recently began programming, so I apologize for the minimal information and ignorance.

Edit: Solved my own problem w/ help

```
if (ObjectManager._r.Next(0, 5) == 3)
{
    NeedUpdate = new List<Point>();
    for (int x = 1; x < Layer1ID.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < Layer2ID.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (Layer1ID[x, y].Updates || Layer2ID[x, y].Updates)
            {
                NeedUpdate.Add(new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (Point P in NeedUpdate)
{
    Layer1ID[P.X, P.Y].Update(P.X, P.Y);
    Layer2ID[P.X, P.Y].Update(P.X, P.Y);
}
```

Comment: Answered my own question, 1 in 60 ticks, I get a list of objects that need to be updated every tick, and update that list of objects.

Comment: I'm not sure if GetLength() just returns an underlying field but I would look at replacing that with a local variable to avoid the unecessary lookup on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not answering your question, I would like to point out problems with your loop conditions.

First, the condition `X != 99 - 1` looks strange. It is the same as `X < 98` in this context. The same holds for `Y`. Since `Y < 98`, if you increment `Y` by one, `Y` is still `Y < 99` and will never be `Y > 98`!

Arrays go from 0 to N-1. Let us assume that you have declared something like

```
const int N = 99;

Layer[,] layer = new Layer[N, N];
```

You would make two nested loops

```
for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        layer[x,y].Update(x,y);
    }
}
```

---

In .NET 4.0 there is a parallel for statement, however if you are updating the UI, what your `Update` statement suggests, then a parallel processing is of little help. Only "pure" calculations will experience an increased calculation power when using parallel processing. Also, the single tasks must have a substantial amount of work to process; otherwise the overhead associated with parallel processing will outweigh the benefits.

See [Parallel.For Method in .NET 4.0 vs the C# For Loop](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=608).

Comment: I substituted in 99 for Layer1ID.GetLength(0) & (1)

Comment: Not only pure calculations benefit from parallel processing; for example, I maintain Castle Transactions which contains transactional file systems. It allows a lot of benefits from parallel IO, in READ COMMITTED mode.

Comment: Yes, however your example has more to do with asynchronicity than parallel processing; i.e. one process (or task) is waiting for data from an input stream, while the other is doing something useful. My statement was more about multiplying the calculating power.